# efficient way to get last two records in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class say

```
class Content{

  String content
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

}
```

There are few content records in the database. I want to retrieve the latest two records. What is an efficient way to query two latest records in Grails? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Hibernate?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Isn't

```
Content.list(max: 2, sort: "dateCreated", order: "desc")
```

a possibility?

Answer (score 4):

Whatever choice of "weapon" you make...

**HQL query**

```
def query = "SELECT content from Content order by lastUpdated desc"
def data = Content.executeQuery(query,[max: 2, offset: 0])
```

**SQL query**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY lastUpdated DESC LIMIT 2
```

**Grails createCriteria:**

```
def c = Content.createCriteria()
def results = c.list {
    order("lastUpdated", "desc")
    maxResults(2)
}
```

... the main principle of best choice stays the same - **order descendingly and get 2 results**. 
If data to retrieve is so trivial, there is no need for actual SQL or HQL queries. You can use Grails functionality, it will not leave any marks on performance.

Comment: I would not advocate for any of those approaches.  Why not a `where` query?

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `HQL` query as -

```
String queryString = "select content from Content order by lastUpdated desc"

List contentList = Content.executeQuery(queryString,[max: 2, offset: 0])
```